# How to make the animation like digitalocean website?

Tags: animation, web, demo

Is there any tools that can help me to make a demo animation like the [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com) website? [image]

Answer (score 1):

They're using a software called [recordit.co](http://recordit.co/)

Answer (score 0):

Their animation is a gif file. You can record a video using software like camtasia and then convert the video to a .gif and set as background of a div on your site.

https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html